# How to send pdf file to server in android studio

Tags: android, http, pdf

I can't send pdf file to server. I'm using AsyncTask
My Code:

```
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            int maxBufferSize = 1024;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(url_path);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setUseCaches(false);
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

                OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
                InputStream inputStream = c.getContentResolver().openInputStream(path);

                int bytesAvailable = inputStream.available();
                int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                outputStream.flush();
                inputStream.close();
```

But i want to send pdf file and more params. Pdf file key "file". Help me guys

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Retrofit` and `Multipart.part` to send any types of file to rest API..

Comment: you're welcome. If my answer helped you, please select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

create class `AndroidMultiPartEntity`,

```
public class AndroidMultiPartEntity extends MultipartEntity {

private final ProgressListener listener;

public AndroidMultiPartEntity(final ProgressListener listener) {
    super();
    this.listener = listener;
}

public AndroidMultiPartEntity(final HttpMultipartMode mode,
                              final ProgressListener listener) {
    super(mode);
    this.listener = listener;
}

public AndroidMultiPartEntity(HttpMultipartMode mode, final String boundary,
                              final Charset charset, final ProgressListener listener) {
    super(mode, boundary, charset);
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public void writeTo(final OutputStream outstream) throws IOException {
    super.writeTo(new CountingOutputStream(outstream, this.listener));
}

public static interface ProgressListener {
    void transferred(long num);
}

public static class CountingOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {

    private final ProgressListener listener;
    private long transferred;

    public CountingOutputStream(final OutputStream out,
                                final ProgressListener listener) {
        super(out);
        this.listener = listener;
        this.transferred = 0;
    }

    public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        out.write(b, off, len);
        this.transferred += len;
        this.listener.transferred(this.transferred);
    }

    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        out.write(b);
        this.transferred++;
        this.listener.transferred(this.transferred);
    }
}}
```

another class `UploadFileToServer`

```
public class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
private long totalSize = 0;
private Context context;
private String url;
private ImageUploadCallBackListener listener;
private UploadFileModel uploadFileModel;
private boolean isError = false;
private int statusCode = 400;

public UploadFileToServer(Context context, UploadFileModel uploadFileModel, String url, ImageUploadCallBackListener listener) {
    this.context = context;
    this.uploadFileModel = uploadFileModel;
    this.url = url;
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    return uploadFile();
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private String uploadFile() {
    String responseString = null;

    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    httpParams.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

    try {
        AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE,
                new AndroidMultiPartEntity.ProgressListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void transferred(long num) {
                        publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                    }
                });

        if (uploadFileModel.isBitmap()) {
            // Adding file data to http body
            entity.addPart(uploadFileModel.getContainer(), new ByteArrayBody(Utils.getBytesFromBitmap(context, uploadFileModel.getFileBitmap()), "image/jpeg", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));
        } else if (uploadFileModel.getFileList() != null && uploadFileModel.getFileList().size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < uploadFileModel.getFileList().size(); i++) {
                entity.addPart(uploadFileModel.getContainer(), new FileBody(uploadFileModel.getFileList().get(i)));
            }
        } else {
            entity.addPart(uploadFileModel.getContainer(), new FileBody(new File(uploadFileModel.getFilePath())));

        }

        totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
        httppost.addHeader(WebserviceConstant.WS_AUTHORIZATION, PrefHelper.getInstance().getString(PrefHelper.TAG_HEADER_TOKEN, WebserviceConstant.WS_HEADER_TOKEN));
        httppost.setEntity(entity);

        // Making server call
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

        statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == RestClient.SUCCESS_CODE) {
            // Server response
            responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
        } else {
            responseString = "Error occurred!";
            isError = true;
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        responseString = e.toString();
        isError = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        responseString = e.toString();
        isError = true;
    }

    return responseString;

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    if (isError) {
        listener.failure(result, statusCode);
    } else {
        listener.success(result);
    }
}

public interface ImageUploadCallBackListener {

    public void success(String response);

    public void failure(String failure, int statusCode);
}}
```

Use where ever you want,

```
UploadFileToServer uploadFileToServer = new UploadFileToServer(context, uploadFileModel, postUrl,
                    new UploadFileToServer.ImageUploadCallBackListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void success(String response) {
                            // success code
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failure(String failure, int statusCode) {
                            // failure code
                        }
                    });
            uploadFileToServer.execute();
```

i created this class for image uploading, you can change as per your requirement.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I solved this problem with different way. Thank you so much <3